# How to watch localstorage in Vue.js 2

Tags: typescript, vue.js, addeventlistener, watch, vue-property-decorator

How do I know about changes in Banana.vue?

I using, addEventListener, @watch...
But, not working........................

index.vue is import Apple.vue, Banana.vue

in Apple.vue
`localStorage.setItem('fruit', 'apple)`

in Banana.vue

```js
@watch(localStorage.getItem('fruit' || '')
    changeFruit() {
    this.fruit = localStorage.getItem('fruit')
}
```

Comment: You can do this with native `storage` events, not Vue reactivity. But you're likely asking about the wrong thing. Use a global store - Vuex, Pinia. Both have plugins to sync with LS

Answer (score 0):

use `getter` and `setter`

```
data() {
    return {
      get token() {
        return localStorage.getItem('token') || 0;
      },
      set token(value) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', value);
        this.fruit = localStorage.getItem('fruit')

      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: in Typescript, How to use data: ???

Comment: It won't be reactive across multiple comps

Answer (score 0):

`LocalStorage` is not reactive but you can access the localStorage value in the component like this **:**

```js
Vue.component('apple', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<p>{{ childmsg }}</p>',
  mounted() {
    localStorage.setItem('fruit', 'apple');
  }
});

Vue.component('banana', {
  data: {
    fruit: ''
  },
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<p>{{ childmsg }}</p>',
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.fruit) {
      this.fruit = localStorage.fruit;
      console.log(this.fruit);
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <apple childmsg="This is Apple"></apple>
  <banana childmsg="This is Banana"></banana>
</div>
```